# translate method in Graphics

Tags: java, printing

I cam across this recently : [here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/printing/examples/HelloWorldPrinter.java)

```
 public int print(Graphics g, PageFormat pf, int page) throws
                                                    PrinterException {

    if (page > 0) { /* We have only one page, and 'page' is zero-based */
        return NO_SUCH_PAGE;
    }

    /* User (0,0) is typically outside the imageable area, so we must
     * translate by the X and Y values in the PageFormat to avoid clipping
     */
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g;
    g2d.translate(pf.getImageableX(), pf.getImageableY()); // line 2

    g.drawString("Hello world!", 100, 100);

    /* tell the caller that this page is part of the printed document */
    return PAGE_EXISTS;
}
```

I don't understand the line 2 *(commented)* in this snippet.*`(g2d.translate(pf.getImageableX(), pf.getImageableY());)`*   g2d is a reference of `Graphics2d`and `translate` is a method found in Graphic class. Then how does it work ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edit:** The translate method is found in both the Graphics2D class and in the Graphics class since Graphics2D is a child class of Graphics. Being a child of Graphics, it implements all of its methods (including translate), which is why it works.

The translate method in your example is used to move the g2d's origin point to pf's origin point.

Basically, what it does is tell the program to translate (move) every point from g2d to pf's corresponding point.

Let's say g2d starts at (0,0) and pf starts at (100,100), after the translation, g2d's (0,100) point would now be at (100,200), which is pf's (0,100) point since it doesn't start at the same place.

I'm having a hard time making it clear and easy to understand, but if you don't understand what I mean, I'll try explaining it better or just delete the answer altogether and let someone else explain it.

Comment: I know what is translate method used for.You did not answer what i asked !

Comment: I revised my answer after re-reading your question. Does it answer it now or am I better of deleting the answer? If it doesn't, try to make your question clearer as I don't know what else the question might refer to.

Comment: @ Adam Smith thank you ! And what does `page > 0` condition check ?

Comment: @grassPro It checks to see if the index supplied (ie: page number) is valid. Since in your example I'm guessing they're only trying to print a one-page document (which would mean index 0), an index number greater than 0 would mean a page that doesn't exist, so the rest of the code shouldn't be run since the page is invalid.

Answer (score 0):

The code looks like it comes from a `java.awt.print.Printable` implementation. This is supposed to draw content to a Graphics object which is set to the printer. The `translate` call is used if the PageFormat has top/left margins, so the content starts within the printable area of the PageFormat, instead of at 0,0 on the paper, which is not within the printable area.

Comment: what if we dont call graphic.translate before printing?